# React - Pass multiple option arguments/values onChange

Tags: reactjs, select, parameters, arguments, html-select

I have a component being rendered by it's parent. There is a select field with a mapped out set of `options` based on what is passed as props. I would like to pass back to the parent both the `id` as well as the `name` of the object which is being mapped out in the option return ... see below

```
let availableProgramNames = props.program_names.map(p => {
    return(
      <option one={p.id} two={p.name} className="universal-program-name">{p.name}</option>
    )
  })
```

I also tried doing something like `value={[p.id, p.name]}` and then running a split in the handleChange, this resulted in the state being changed properly but then the select field wouldn't update despite when re-rendering the value of `props.new_program.name` was found to be updated. No clue there...

```
<select value={props.new_program.name} onChange={props.handleNameChange}>
              <option selected>Please Choose a Name</option>
              {availableProgramNames}
            </select>
```

Comment: Can you provide all your components as a whole if this is not a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    program_names: [
      { id: 1, name: "foo" },
      { id: 2, name: "bar" },
    ],
  }

  availableProgramNames = this.state.program_names.map(p => {
    return (
      <option key={p.id}>{p.name}</option>
    )
  })

  handleNameChange = (e) => {
    const { selectedIndex } = e.target.options;
    const {program_names} = this.state;
    const {name,id} = program_names[ selectedIndex -1 ];
    console.log(name,id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.handleNameChange}>
          <option>Please Choose a Name</option>
          {this.availableProgramNames}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally handle this logic in the parent component, but you can also create a callback function for the onChange event that finds the selected option based on the value of the control.

```js
const options = [
    {id: 1, name: 'bill'},
    {id: 2, name: 'sally'},
]

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const selectedOption = options.find(option => option.id === +e.target.value);
    props.handleNameChange(selectedOption);
}
return (
    <select onChange={handleChange}>
        {options.map((option, key) => (
            <option value={option.id} key={key}>{option.name}</option>
        ))}
    </select>
);
```